# jQuery mobile Rangeslider - don't show numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, rangeslider

I am using the [jQuery Mobile range slider](https://api.jquerymobile.com/rangeslider/). I want to use it with time ranges.

Is it possible to hide the to value boxes which are located left and right of the slider?

See picture:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxCGg.png]

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the inputs with CSS:

```
.ui-rangeslider input {
    display: none;
}
.ui-rangeslider-sliders{
    margin: 15px !important;
}
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/ZGV4v/1/)**